# can not access to tomcat7 manager application

Tags: software-installation, tomcat7

I've installed **TOMCAT7** via synaptic but can not access manager application. What am I doing wrong or what is missing, I can not figure out.

*My complete settings and o/p are listed below:*

When I do `http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html`,
it shows **403 Access Denied**.**You are not authorized to view this page...**

My OS is **Ubuntu 14.04**

```
**java -version**
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

**the o/p of the command:**

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps$ ls
manager  ROOT
```

**The o/p of the command shows:**

```
ls -l /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Aug  3 18:31 manager -> /usr/share/tomcat7-admin/manager
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug  3 10:42 ROOT
```

and I've set **/etc/environment** as:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

CATALINA_HOME="/var/lib/tomcat7"
CATALINE_BASE="/var/lib/tomcat7" 
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"
```

**tomcat-users.xml file**

```
<tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>  
</tomcat-users>
```

Please can anyone explain what is missing or what is going wrong with this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Guys!
Please help me solve this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the tomcat-users.xml file inside the

**/etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml**

my previous settings:

```
<tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>  
</tomcat-users>
```

changed to:

```
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Now I can access the link

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html
```